# highlight "partial" duplicates across entire sheet in Google Sheets using conditional formatting

Tags: formatting, duplicates, conditional-statements, highlight, partial

Im trying to highlight partial duplicates in google sheets using conditional formatting. I need to highlight duplicates across multiple columns and rows in any matching cells. so far I'm using this...

```
=countif(INDIRECT({"C2:Z18"}),C2)>1
```

Which works to a degree, but it only highlights exact matches. I need to find a way to highlight partial matches also. The data I'm using is basically a 4 digit bus number followed by a fuel reading, like this...

1429 
1384
1429/167

I need to find a way to get the conditional formatting formula to only match the first 4 characters of each cell. So that it ignores the following fuel reading. I have tried this...

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C2:Z18"}),LEFT(C2,4)&"*")>1
```

But it malfunctions and highlights every cell in the selected range, which is listed in the conditional format rule.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a genius over at the Google Product Support Forums named Isai Alvarado I finally have the solution...

=if(C2<>"",ArrayFormula(countif(left($C$2:$Z$18,4),left(C2,4)))>1)

I hope this helps anyone else trying to highlight partial duplicates across multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

have you tired using countifs instead of the countif function? Countifs is capable of searching across multiple columns for duplicates whereas countif is used to search just the column its applied to. I see you have utilized the "indirect()" function to get around this limitation. try the following.

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:Z18;LEFT(C2;4)&"*")>1
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Using your solution causes the whole range to be highlighted, not just the duplicates. That's why I included the indirect() on the countif to get around that problem.